# Link to the meme in Discord.py Meme command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord.py and have made a meme command using AIOHTTP. I want the embed title to be the link to the meme and the footer should show the upvotes and all that stuff like in the screenshot.[image]

Here is the code

````
@client.command(aliases=['memes'])
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Meme', description=None)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            
            
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            
            
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, content=None)
    ```
````

Comment: You can check the embed source with [carl-bot](https://carl.gg/)(!embedsource) command and copy it.

Comment: As having made a similar command myself, I would advise you to use the Reddit PRAW package. It will do this for you. I believe, and correct me if I am wrong, that you only have to do something similar to `meme.url` or `meme.link` to get the link to the meme.

Comment: @Ceres I don't see any meme command for carl bot

Comment: You can use the `embedsource` command to get the source of the meme's embed. With the source, you could redesign your own embed, imitating the meme

Answer (score 1):

replace it with this code
Toutorial
step 1: install praw (pip install praw)
step 2: go to https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps create app
step 3: copy client_id and client_secret
step 4:run bot

```
@bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):

    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='clientidhere',
                     client_secret='clientsecret',
                     user_agent='python')

    memes = reddit.subreddit("memes").random()
    await ctx.send(memes.url)
```